# Story about man unable to wake up from dream

Tags: story-identification, dreams

I am looking for a story which I read a long time back but cannot recall the name. The plot line was:

In a futuristic world, there are dream parlors which provide sleep with dream services. The protagonist is a frequenter of them.

One day, it was found that he is unable to wake up after slipping into a dream. All efforts to wake him up fail, and he keeps on dreaming and sleeping but is medically fit otherwise.

He became a medical case study and was kept alive for centuries. By studying him a lot was learnt about hibernation and the code to interstellar travel in hibernation was cracked through that knowledge.

Eventually after a few centuries the government asked his custodians for justification for spending billions per century to keep him alive.

His custodians revealed that:

> he is the last person alive who is capable of dreaming. The entire human race has lost the capability to dream. So he should be kept alive as long as possible as a rare treasure to humanity.

Comment: When was "a long time ago"? You may not remember exactly, but can you give a ballpark? What is a long time ago to one person may only be a handful of years to another.

Comment: Damn, I have read this before, but I cannot for the life of me remember the name of the story. I think it was a short story from an anthology by Heinlein, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Sounds like a good story...

Were there aliens/robots or anything?